# terraform jsondecode secrets manager ssh key containing escape characters not readable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, ssh-keys, aws-secrets-manager

I'm facing a surprising issue with the terraform code.

I have in AWS secrets manager a ssh key (one liner with escape characters). If I add this as a string in the values file everything works file.

but if I want to use the aws provider with aws_secretsmanager_secret_version data source and using jsondecode I cannot use the same string althouth it is very nicely visible in secrets manager.

I can use python, bash, go to get the same escaped ssh key but not terraform jsondecode as I understood it's NOT POSSIBLE ? :))

Please, did anyone faced this issue ?

aws -> secretsmanager:

```
KEY      VALUE
{
"ssh_key": "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\nb3Blb.._REDACTED__"
}
```

Terraform:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
  provider = aws.creds_provider
  count = 1
  name  = "generic/credentials/terraform"
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secrets_version" {
  provider = aws.creds_provider
  count     = 1 
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets[0].id
}

provider "test" {
  host      = "aa.bb.cc"
  username = "root"
  ssh_key =  jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets_version[0].secret_string)["ssh_key"]
}
```

Comment: If this is not production, can you try saving the key as plain text?

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this is production. I can see what the issue is after marking the output as nonsensitive. The jsondecode is adding extra escape characters to the string ... f.e. if the string is -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n after using jsondecode() the output is -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\\n with an extra \
This is really weird as I expected that if the string can be added to the secrets manager it can also be obtained but it seems to be the only option at the moment
Still not working as expected

Comment: For example I added extra escape characters and terraform jsondecode added even more escape characters, f.e. -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\\\\\\\\n. This is so strange

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question by myself yesterday. I am really shocked that nobody has faced this issue before on stackoverflow :D

When the result comes from the jsondecode with the extra escape characters, one must use replace to restore the SSH key to original state.

```
ssh_private_key = replace(
    jsondecode(
data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets_version[0].secret_string)["ssh_key"],
    "\\n",
    "\n"
  )
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue

This is what I had to use :

```
replace(jsondecode(replace(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.cloudfront_key.secret_string,"\n","|")).public,"|","\n")
```